# How to distinguish between default value and inputed/changed

Tags: go

I have a struct:

```
package main

type Test struct {
    FieldInt int
    FieldBool bool
    FieldString string
}

func main() {
    test := Test{}
    ...
}
```

Default values of this struct is:

- FieldInt: 0
- FieldBool: false
- FieldString: ""

For example, a user can change `FieldInt`. It can be a positive, negative number and 0.

And I want to check, that the user changed it (but he/she can set 0):

```
if(test.FieldInt was changed) {
    // do something
}
```

But if the user inputted 0 then I can't distinguish between default value and inputted/changed one.

**How to distinguish between default value and inputted/changed one?**

Comment: There is no way to distinguish 0 from 0. What context are you using this type in where you don't know what is happening to it?

Comment: I have a server (backend). Users can input some data at a client (i.e. browser), for examle: timeoffset (required), gender (required, in code context - 0, 1, 2), and such things which are required and can have value is 0. This data is sended to the backend in JSON. I have to validate this data before it will be saved to a DB. After parse the data, all values which weren't filled in by users will have default values even if users didn't select anything. Also, some values can't be used without the zero value (-n ... , -1, 0, 1 ...., n).

Comment: Then you're asking how to different between the default value and an unset value when uaamrshaling JSON, in which case you want a pointer as Flimzy pointed out.

Comment: But how work with case like this: https://play.golang.org/p/CD0s9gPZA6 ?

Comment: You either use a helper function(https://play.golang.org/p/oQZqKC4PJe), or assign the value outside of the struct literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One common way to distinguish between the zero value and an unset value is with pointers:

```
type Test struct {
    FieldInt    *int
    FieldBool   *bool
    FieldString *string
}
```

This won't be an appropriate solution for every situation, but it is an appropriate answer for unmarshaling JSON.

Comment: I have one more question. How can I fill a struct of pointers in runtime? Please, see this example: https://play.golang.org/p/CD0s9gPZA6

Comment: @RayCarrey Two possible solutions added to your example: https://play.golang.org/p/zqJkvcewuy

Answer (score 1):

I would personally tend towards the solution Flimzy provided here for it's simplicity. But just to provide alternative options, you could add a flag for each property to indicate whether or not it's been updated.

```
type Test struct {
    FieldInt int
    FieldBool bool
    FieldString string

    intUpdated bool
    boolUpdated bool
    stringUpdate bool
    // lets not export these though since it's for managing state
    // internally and consumers of this object shouldn't modify these values
}
```

To me this is rather a strange thing to see in Go code, however it would be very common place in JS UI apps (almost all modern apps have 'stores' which monitor the state of the UI and typically have flags to indicate whether a value in the UI has changed from what's in the store or not). For back end systems, you usually see even MORE overhead to go with this, for example it would be very common to have  fields to store the last time of update and the name of the user who updated it. In fact, that is probably the norm within the data stores for back end services.